# Multithreaded recursion to calculate nth fibonacci series element

Tags: c, multithreading, recursion, pthreads

I have written the following code to calculate the nth fibonacci series element using recursion and multithreading:

```
typedef struct thread_data {
    int n;
    int result;
} thread_data;

void *mt_fib(void *arg){
    
    thread_data *tdata = (thread_data *)arg;

    if(tdata->n <= 1){
        tdata->result = tdata->n;
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        
    }
    
    thread_data thread_data1, thread_data2;
    thread_data1.n = tdata->n-1;
    thread_data2.n = tdata->n-2;

    pthread_t thread1, thread2;

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, mt_fib, (void *)&thread_data1);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, mt_fib, (void *)&thread_data2);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    tdata->result = thread_data1.result + thread_data2.result;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int mt_fib_main(int n){
    thread_data tdata;
    tdata.n = n;

    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, mt_fib, (void *)&tdata);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);

    return tdata.result;
}
```

This works for upto 22 terms but keeps giving a segmentation fault after that. I have used *long long* for *result* and *n* but that doesnt change anything. Could anyone give any leads about why this is happening?

Comment: How many threads do you think that creates?

Comment: This code creates an exponential number of system threads. Threads are a very precious resource and should not be wasted. This is useless to create more threads than the number of hardware thread (aka. hyperthreads) and most of the time not very useful to create more threads than the number of core. The number of threads that can be created on a given platform is bounded. While some system limit this to ~1000 others reach ~256000. In practice, creating so many threads will slow down the whole system and the computation. *You need a cut-off strategy*.

Comment: This code spends literally all of its time creating, then waiting, on threads. It is actually *worse* than just a simple recursion formula, since you're still recursing just as much, only now you're splaying it across scheduled threads rather than the call activation stack. Draw a tree of a regular recursive fib(5), now consider every node in that tree is ultimately on its own thread, e.g. fib(5) is 15 threads. fib(6) would yield 24 threads. fib(7) required 39 threads, fib(8) would be 63 threads, etc. It doesn't take long to see how this is murder on the scheduler.

Comment: By the way, the nth fibonacci term can be computed in linear time instead of an exponential time. In fact, it can even be computed in logarithmic time. Additionally, note that you only need to create 1 thread and not 2 per recursion. The thread that is currently waiting can actually compute one branch of the tree.

Comment: So possibly you were told, as a course assignment, to compute Fibonacci numbers using threads. But using one thread per addition is not the right way to do that. What was the wording of the assignment?

Comment: @JérômeRichard In fact it can be calculated in *O(1)* time for *N* sufficiently large.

Comment: @user207421 Considering overflows in the complexity is not really fair since the OP probably do not want this ;) .